# Relational Data Help Silverstripe

Tags: php, orm, silverstripe

Im trying to extend https://github.com/Quadra-Digital/silverstripe-schema to be able to better handle nested schemas. I've managed to get it working all though it breaks one of the very useful features Dynamic Values.

It currently uses a DataObject called RelatedObject to map its related object which works fine when there is only one level of nesting. However once you get further into it and have SchemaInstances nested upon SchemaPropertys you lose the overarching owner, and the RelatedObject becomes the Property that the Instance is nested under.

```
class SchemaInstance extends DataObject {

    private static $db = [
      'ParentClass' => 'Varchar(255)'
    ];
    private static $has_one = [
        'RelatedObject' => 'DataObject',
        'Schema'        => 'Schema',
    ];

    private static $has_many = [
        'Properties' => 'SchemaProperty'
    ];



class SchemaProperty extends DataObject {

    private static $db = [
        'Title'         => 'Varchar(255)',
        'ValueStatic'   => 'Varchar(255)',
        'ValueDynamic'  => 'Varchar(255)'
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
      'ParentSchema'  => 'SchemaInstance'
    ];

    private static $has_many = [
      'NestedSchemas' => 'SchemaInstance'
    ];
```

This is what is currently saved when I created the nested schema instance.

```
  52    SchemaInstance  2018-03-04 04:28:38 2018-03-04 04:28:38 0   File    8   0   96  SchemaProperty
```

I need it to look like this

```
52  SchemaInstance  2018-03-04 04:28:38 2018-03-04 04:28:38 0   File    8   0   96  *ActualParentClass*
```

I have tried getting the owner in the SchemaObjectExtension (Which works fine, I just can't figure out how to use that rather than the default)

```
class SchemaObjectExtension extends DataExtension {
    private static $has_many = [
        'SchemaInstances' => 'SchemaInstance.RelatedObject',

    ];
```

I'd be happy with just being able to save the owner class to the db somehow and the reference that. I've tried getting it from the DataObject but it gives a 
"getOwner() is not a method on Dataobject" error.
Thanks for any help